# Separate cell text to one word per line

Tags: excel, vba

How can I convert a range of cells in one row (B2:CT2) to one word per line (in the same cell)?

I have code that extends the column out but it pushes all the text to one line, so it is too long.

```
Sub AutoFitWrappedText()
    With Range("B2:CT2").EntireColumn
        .ColumnWidth = 255 ' maximum width
        .AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Example cell: Dog and Cat

What it looks like:

```
Do

g

an

cat
```

What I'm aiming for:

```
Dog

and

Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use a formula. Make sure Wrap Text is turned on.

`=SUBSTITUTE("DOG AND CAT", " ", CHAR(10))`

VBA:

```vb
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:CT")
        .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=vbCrLf, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
        .WrapText = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Anything VBA related, the cells can't take a hard coded bar formula